# Why isn't this converting data arrays to nans in xarray properly?

Tags: python, arrays, object, python-xarray

I have two data arrays in an xarray object where I am trying to convert the first column of every row to a nan.

The first data array, called data_array, has a shape of (3505, 46) and belongs to xarray_obj_1.

The second data array, also called data_array, has a shape of (3504, 136) and belongs to xarray_obj_2. (xarray_obj_2 has the same data_array name as xarray_obj_1 because both xarray objects come from the same instrument, just at a different power level.)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    data_array_1 = xarray_obj_1['data_array'].values
    data_array_1[:,0] = np.nan
    xarray_obj_1 = xarray_obj_1.assign(data_array = xarray_obj_1['data_array'])

    data_array_2 = xarray_obj_2['data_array'].values
    data_array_2[:,0] = np.nan
    xarray_obj_2 = xarray_obj_2.assign(data_array = xarray_obj_2['data_array'])
```

For some reason, however, the first column of every row becomes a nan for data_array_1 in xarray_obj_1, but not for data_array_2 in xarray_obj_2. Here is what I get when I print them out:

```
print(xarray_obj_1['data_array'].values)
```

gives me:

```
[[     nan   3.6345   5.9408 ... -10.8594 -12.4048 -14.795 ]
 [     nan   6.7247   5.9889 ... -12.592  -13.0183  -4.0337]
 [     nan   3.2589   2.8826 ... -11.8943 -14.0153 -13.5239]
 ...
 [     nan  -9.8147  -7.6685 ... -10.9449 -15.7236 -11.001 ]
 [     nan  -6.7883  -9.8305 ... -10.6852 -15.074  -14.5383]
 [     nan  -8.8625  -8.5386 ...  -9.106  -18.745  -13.6973]]
```

while

```
print(xarray_obj_2['data_array'].values)
```

gives me:

```
[[  0.      12.3087   9.2386 ... -11.4609 -17.247  -14.9684]
 [  0.      12.2955   5.9    ... -12.8284 -14.6057 -14.4841]
 [  0.      14.2813  10.9035 ... -13.08   -14.8733  -7.5755]
 ...
 [  0.      16.7364  10.1303 ... -17.7308 -12.5128 -14.5654]
 [  0.      11.8087   7.4737 ...  -5.6225 -10.0215 -12.7733]
 [  0.      17.5023  13.4416 ... -11.1717 -12.7586 -12.3139]]
```

I am at a loss for why doing one bit of code for xarray_obj_1 works properly, but does not work properly when the same bit of code is used for xarray_obj_2. Does anyone know the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what's up with your data (could you post a minimally reproducible example that also either generates or links to the data you're using?), but here's a way that you might be able to circumvent the issue.

Assigning in `xarray` is a bit of a tricky set of things to remember, but you don't have to use `.assign()` to do so. [This](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing) bit of the `xarray` docs in particular may be useful to review. Following that method of assigning new values, using the `.loc[]` structure (and randomly generated data),

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

xarray_obj_1 = xr.Dataset({'data_array':(('dim1','dim2'),np.random.rand(3505, 46))},
                          coords={'dim1':(('dim1'),np.arange(0,3505)),
                                  'dim2':(('dim2'),np.arange(0,46))})
xarray_obj_1['data_array'].loc[{'dim2':0}] = np.nan

# To see that the nans were added
print(xarray_obj_1['data_array'])
```

Alternatively, you can use vectorized indexing as well:

```
xarray_obj_1 = xr.Dataset({'data_array':(('dim1','dim2'),np.random.rand(3505, 46))},
                          coords={'dim1':(('dim1'),np.arange(0,3505)),
                                  'dim2':(('dim2'),np.arange(0,46))})
xarray_obj_1['data_array'][:,0] = np.nan

# To see that the nans were added
print(xarray_obj_1['data_array'])
```

If this doesn't work with your data, please post an example to either generate your data, or a link to it so we can see what you're working with.